# Binding 'this' to the upper class using OOP

Tags: javascript, class, oop, this

I'm trying to make a game using Classes to keep my code cleaner and more readable, but something isn't working.

In the 'create' function in my `Canvas` class I define `this.ctx` and call it again in another class called `Tile`. I want to use that `this.ctx` everywhere in all classes. But in that class the `this`'s I defined in the `Canvas` class don't exist anymore in the `Tile` class and neither do they in the `App` class. I have tried returning the `this` object but that didn't seem to work.

Can anyone help my with this problem. Thanks in advance!

```
class App {
    constructor() {
        this.gridX      = 4;
        this.gridY      = 4;
        this.blockSize  = 100;
        this.width      = this.gridX * this.blockSize;
        this.height     = this.gridY * this.blockSize;
        this.grid       = new Array(this.gridX).fill(new Array(this.gridY));

        document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
            const canvas = new Canvas();
            canvas.create(this.width, this.height);
            this.makeGrid();
        });
    }

    makeGrid() {
        this.grid.forEach((value, i) => {
            this.grid.forEach((value, j) => {
                new Tile().createTile(i, j);
            });
        });
    }
}

class Canvas extends App {
    create(width, height) {
        this.canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
        this.canvas.setAttribute('width', width);
        this.canvas.setAttribute('height', height);
        document.body.appendChild(this.canvas);
        this.ctx = this.canvas.getContext('2d');
    }
}

class Tile extends App {
    createTile(x, y) {
        this.ctx.fillStyle = 'white';
        this.ctx.strokeStyle = "red";
        this.ctx.fillRect(j + 1, i + 1, this.blockSize - 2, this.blockSize - 2);
    }
}

new App();
```

Comment: You seem to be confused about inheritance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your `Tile` class does virtually nothing, I'm not sure there's much reason for `createTile` to be on `Tile` rather than on `App`. Regardless: There's no reason `Tile` should inherit from `App`, so remove the `extends App` from its declaration. (Same with `Canvas`.)

But if you want `Tile` to have access to the canvas, the usual thing is to pass it a reference to the canvas in its constructor:

```
// In Tile
constructor(ctx) {
    this.ctx = ctx;
}
```

then when using it:

```
new Tile(this.ctx).createTile(i, j);
```

Comment: I understanding it more now, but I want to declare a this variable in the Tile class and then be able to call it in the class above it, because I do want to use `extends`  and work with inheritance.

Comment: @YounessArsalane: The inheritance in this case makes no sense at all and isn't being used correctly. Inheritance can be useful, but only when there's an "is a" relationship between the subclass and the superclass. For instance, `Car extends Vehicle` because Car "is a" Vehicle. Tile is not an App. Canvas is not an App. The App *has* Tiles, and a Canvas, which is not an inheritance relationship (it's a containment relationship).

Comment: That makes sense. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

```
class App {
    constructor() {
        this.gridX      = 4;
        this.gridY      = 4;
        this.blockSize  = 100;
        this.width      = this.gridX * this.blockSize;
        this.height     = this.gridY * this.blockSize;
        this.grid       = new Array(this.gridX).fill(new Array(this.gridY));

        document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
            const canvas = new Canvas();
            canvas.create(this.width, this.height);
            this.makeGrid();
        });
    }

    makeGrid() {
        this.grid.forEach((value, i) => {
            this.grid.forEach((value, j) => {
                new Tile().createTile(i, j);
            });
        });
    }
}

class Canvas {
    constructor(){}
    create(width, height) {
        this.canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
        this.canvas.setAttribute('width', width);
        this.canvas.setAttribute('height', height);
        document.body.appendChild(this.canvas);
        this.ctx = this.canvas.getContext('2d');
    }
}

class Tile extends Canvas {
    constructor(){
        super();
    }
    createTile(x, y) {
        this.ctx.fillStyle = 'white';
        this.ctx.strokeStyle = "red";
        this.ctx.fillRect(j + 1, i + 1, this.blockSize - 2, this.blockSize - 2);
    }
}

new App();
```

why not try like this way

Answer (score -1):

Looks like you are extending `Tile` from `App` instead of `Canvas`.